# config_stream.is_open() c++ always returns false

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have the following c++ code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string filename("config.txt");
    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    if (argc > 2) {
        std::cerr << "Too many arguments. Usage: \n"
                "<program>\n"
                "or\n"
                "<program> <config-filename>\n" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::ifstream config_stream(filename);
    if (!config_stream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open configuration file " << filename << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The simple program that gets the config file as a command line argument, if this argument is not provided it searches for the config file with the default name in the current directory. 
It worked fine in previous project, but now config_stream.is_open() c++ always returns false even if  the file exists. I want to figure out, is this some kind of bug or I miss something.

Comment: The code looks good, and I get the expected behavior on my side. You said that it worked fine in a previous project? Maybe you ran the previous project with another user or something similar? My only guess is that it has something to do with the file itself. My best guess would be that it's due to permissions. I.e. if I have a file `config.txt` owned by `root:root` with `640` I get the error message, since it's unable to open the file.

Comment: Quite often IDE during the build process creates extra folders and compiler places binary there. And there are no config files in that temporary folder. When IDE runs this binary it makes those temp build folder as current directory which is different from the folder where your source code reside. You can configure override for current folder in IDE and it will for for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such confusing thing happens when you have your data file among source code files or in the root of your project.

**Execution context(i.e. current directory)** is usually wrong from your point of view **when you run** compiled binary while being **in IDE**.

During the build IDE creates temporary folder and places your binary there.
And current directory for the binary usually points to the build folder (where you have no data files which binary expects).

You can instruct your IDE to **use another folder as a current directory** for the run, for example **../**.

Here is how you could configure Intellij Clion to resolve such issue.
[image]

The same thing happens with any other IDE so this issue is not specific for Intellij IDE.